Angular JWT localstorage is not defined
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config:{
    tokenGetter : () => localStorage.getItem('accessToken') ,
    allowedDomains : ["localhost:44382"]
  }
}),

i got error which is  : localStorage is not defined
at JwtInterceptor.tokenGetter --> that showes app.module.ts.
This JwtModule.forRoot is on my app.module.ts

are you using serverside rendering? Then this code may be running on the backend which means there is no localStorage

Yess thank you sir.  I change prerender and ssr to false at angular.json then it works.
